# Animated gif looping more than once after uploading to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, upload, animated-gif, media-library

I have an animated gif that is supposed to only loop once after it is loaded on the page. The image works fine when viewed by itself in the browser, but once I upload it to the WordPress media library, the image loops continuously (which I don't want). It seems that the file is somehow being modified once it is uploaded by WordPress. Has anyone seen this before and is there anyway to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the file stays the same, it`s just the WordPress decoder ignoring the [loop-once mark](/a/28486261).